# Custom shortcode not working

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I tried to make my own shortcode for a first time. I have done all things and there is no syntax error. Can somebody tell me what's the mistake? It's not working.

I have implemented this code into function.php file and Dreamweaver tells me that there is no syntax error.

```
function booknovelist_button( $atts ) {
    // Attributes   
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'style' => 'rfc',
        'link' => 'www.booknovelist.com'
    ), $atts ) );

    $style  = '$atts[style]'; $choice = ' '; $choicehover = ' ';

    if ($style == 'rfc') {
        $choice='link to image';
        $choicehover='link to image';
    }; 

    if ($style == 'sn') {
        $choice='link to image';
        $choicehover='link to image';
    }

    if ($style == 'pon') {
        $choice='link to image';
        $choicehover='link to image';
    }

    if ($style == 'amazon') {
        $choice='link to image';
        $choicehover='link to image'; 
    }

    echo '<div><a href="',$link,'"><img src="',$choice,'" onmouseover="this.src="',$choicehover,'"" onmouseout="this.src="',$choice,'""></a></div> ' ; } 
}

add_shortcode ( 'bn_btn', 'booknovelist_button' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You should review the documentation for **[add_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)** and look at the examples. You are supposed to return the content that is to be output by the shortcode.

```
function footag_func( $atts ) {
    return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode('footag', 'footag_func');
```

So instead of echoing your div, you should return it.

Your code seems to have other syntax errors as well.